# Hide a section by default when form loads

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I am battling with SharePoint forms in InfoPath 2013 with little success.

I wish to hide a section by defualt when the form loads, and display it if a checkbox is checked.

I have the section showing/hiding based on a rule, but I want to hide the section by default, and show it if the checkbox is checked.

I tried setting the value of the checkbox on form load to trigger the hiding, but this didn't work.

It feels like this shouldn't be so difficult, but it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was setting the false() value to the control on form load, this triggered the rule to hide the section as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a "Formatting" rule on the item (section).
And use the check "Hide this control" based on the Conditions you want.